# Razor Intillisense not working with latest MVC 3 tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Just installed MVC3 as I wanted to use intellisense in cshtml files.  Installation went ok, but when I open a file in visual studio i get the following in the output window:

Javascript Intellisense Message: C:\Users\simonm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\BLSPJXWA\jquery.min-fds90[1]..js(19:21831) : Object required

That file does exist.  I attempted to reinstall MVC but no luck.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Started working for apparently no reason the other day..

Answer (score 0):

For me that has worked: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/03/24/razor-tooling-for-mvc3-rc-with-visual-studio-2010-sp1-rtm.aspx

Comment: hmm I already have that version of MVC installed (3.0.20105.0).  Thanks anyway, I may end up doing a clean install of VS as I use Razor quite a lot but MVC very little.